# failed to instantiate th type xmppconnection

Tags: xmpp

I have a problem with eclipse,it says failed to instantiate the type xmppconnection,please tell me what's wrong with my code

here is my code

```
}  

public boolean login(String a,String p){  
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("gcm.googleapis.com", PORT);  
    /**  */  
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);  
    /**  */  
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);  
    /** connection */  
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);  
    try {  
        /**  */  
        connection.connect();  
        /** */  
        connection.login(a, p);  
        /** ?*/  
        //ClientSendThread cst=new ClientSendThread(connection);  
        //cst.start();  
        //ManageClientThread.addClientSendThread(a, cst);  
        return true;  
    } catch (XMPPException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    return false;  
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new smack version using   `XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config)` 

instead of  `XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);`
```